# Compare two columns in pandas DataFrame against the inverse

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with graph content that I need to check for 'bidirectionality' using Python...

```
  src dest  val1  val2
0   A    B     8     9
1   B    A     8     9
2   B    C     7     8
3   D    C     5     6
4   B    A     5     6
```

In this case, the link between source 'A' and destination 'B' has a matching link in the DataFrame from 'B' to 'A'. Thus, I can consider this to be a pair of bidirectional links. Row 0 and row 4 are also bidirectional links...

The link between 'B' and 'C' does not have a corresponding reverse link from 'C' to 'B'.

Any suggestions from the StackOverflow community on ways to identify which links have a matching bidirectional link? or in other words, which rows have a matching row where the values in two columns are transposed/swapped?

A resultant DataFrame that looks like this might work:

```
  src dest  val1  val2  bidir
0   A    B     8     9   True
1   B    A     8     9   True
2   B    C     7     8  False
3   D    C     5     6  False
4   B    A     5     6   True
```

Any assistance you can offer is appreciated.

**Update:**
Gonna add to this, based on the really nice answer that acushner provided, to take his solution to the main problem and then populate the DataFrame as shown in the resultant DataFrame above.

```
>>> df['bidir'] = (df.src + df.dest).isin(df.dest + df.src)

>>> print a
  src dest  val1  val2  bidir
0   A    B     8     9   True
1   B    A     8     9   True
2   B    C     7     8  False
3   D    C     5     6  False
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can just do:

```
(df.src + df.dest).isin(df.dest + df.src)
```

Comment: Yes you're right, thought my answer looked too good, will delete, clever answer